# git clone fails when uses ssh connection

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I used the following command to clone a git repository

```
git clone ssh://git@test.server.com/project.git
```

I placed the key files `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa` in the folder `~/.ssh/` but I get the following error when trying to clone with a above `git` command.

```
ssh -v git@test.server.com
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for test.server.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to test.server.com [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you have already tried...a quick `duckduckgo` :) brought me here: `http://edoceo.com/notabene/ssh-exchange-identification`

Comment: why are you using ssh when it works directly: git clone user@server:~/repos/project.git

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your local key (found in `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) on the server in `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ssh-copy-id](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) to send your public key to the server.